# Does Solr have lossless decimals?

Tags: solr

Does solr have such a datatype? And can I index, sort, facet and perform arithmetic operations etc as if it were float/double?

Comment: would you please explain what exactly do you mean by "lossless"?

Comment: My bad. I mean that floating point losses (0.7 becomes 0.69999999999...) do not happen to such a field.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'lossless' you mean that the precision should not be changed or lost in operations, then BigDecimal is your answer.  See below:

[How to index BigDecimal values in Lucene 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730200/how-to-index-bigdecimal-values-in-lucene-3-0-1)

Comment: I don't think the Solr schema can be used to store the arbitrary precision of the BigDouble (not in a useful way, that would allow you to do range queries, etc)

Answer (score 2):

For money, there is a [currency field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CurrencyField) which is essentially a fixed point number backed by TrieLong.  It can do most arithmetic operations except facet ranges.

Comment: Can I make it as precise (like 4 decimal places) as I want? And what are the other caveats besides facet ranges, like speed?

Comment: I don't think that you can control the decimal places through simple configuration: _The fractional portion of the floating point value is interpreted based upon the currency, via Currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()._

Answer (score 0):

Well since Solr is made in Java, and Java doesn't have absolute losseless precision, you probably don't get that in Solr either. However, you can try the [TrieDoubleField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDoubleField.html) which has the same precision as Java's double (namely double precision).